# Got Error 3001 on RecordSet, don't know why

Tags: sql, vba, mariadb, adodb, recordset

I'm trying to get 4 columns from my MariaDb 5 but while it usually works with this code, I get an error 3001 right now

> Error 3001 - Arguments are of wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in confilct with one another

Here is the code (So far)

```
Sub Rempli_contacts()

    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim Derligne As Integer, i As Integer
    Dim Requete As String

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
        ConnectionDB

    Requete = "SELECT Ref,Nom,Marque,PrixVente FROM Produits_Beta"
            rs.Open Requete, oConnect
End Sub
```

I get the error on line  `rs.Open Requete, oConnect`

Comment: Where is `oConnect` defined/created? Also what is `ConnectionDB`?

Comment: In top of another module, name AcessSQl

`Public oConnect As ADODB.Connection`

Comment: And is that open/created ok before this line?

Comment: Ok that lead me to it. When I launched the Userform it worked, because it was loading AccessSQL BEFORE. So of course it wouldn't work with a simple F5 on it.

Thanks Nathan :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Nathan_Sav pointed out I needed to load oConnect BEFORE, obivously, and it now works perfectly (Welp, can't get it to fill the column of the ListBox yet but that's another story)

Short answer :
Check that all the variables are loaded before executing this macro if you get this message.